How to stop Resharper_LineComment from moving to the below line?
As the title says, it's frustrating since the behaviour is different from stock Visual Studio. I also couldn't find a setting for it anywhere. I'd like the cursor to stay where it is when I comment out the line I'm on.
ex:
imagine || is the selection cursor.
||void Foo()
becomes
// void Foo()
||
while I want the cursor to stay where it is.
I tried looking for settings that changed this behaviour, looked up if there were any similar questions online, and couldn't find any solution.

Unfortunately, there is no way to change this behavior now. There is an issue on YouTrack about this: RSRP-461526 Don't move the caret to the next line after (un)commenting.
